# how to check running containers with containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I've switched to containerd in a k8s cluster.

There's 2 pods running on one node, 2 github runners.

I used to check on a host what containers were running with "docker container ls" but how to check this when containerd is used?

```
sudo ctr container ls
```

comes back with nothing

Comment: Try with `crictl ps` & `crictl pods`. To be honest, I'm a bit confused between cri-o and containerd as well. Looking at kubespray especially, I would have both options, while setting "containerd" as a runtime, I would still end up using crictl listing/viewing pods, while as you suggest: ctr doesn't  show anything.

Comment: ah yes, crictl does the job. Is that a general name so that it works with any cri?

Comment: Check your `/etc/crictl.yaml`: when using containerd, your crictl configuration would just query containerd's socket file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to namespace to list command

```
ctr -n k8s.io containers list
```

To list available namespaces run

```
ctr ns ls
```

Comment: For microk8s you have to prefix command with `microk8s ctr ...`

Answer (score 1):

I feel relevant and important to note that:

```
ctr c ls
```

lists **all** containers, i.e. either stopped or running.

In accordance with the question title: to precisely list all **running** containers (in the sense of docker terminology) you need to use this command:

```
ctr task list
```

or the shorthand

```
ctr t ls
```